# How to search for a record and then delete it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

How to search for the ttoken record by mobile no. and then delete that record?

User.rb:

`field :ttokens,  type: Hash, :default => {} # Stored as hash over numbers`

Normally the value of ttokens, in the rails console, are as follows:

```
ttokens: {"919839398393"=>{"atoken"=>"f704e803061e594150b09ad8akabfc6105ac85ab", "confirmed"=>true}, "91812798765"=>{"atoken"=>"255cb70926978b93eik67edb52fa23a163587b4b", "confirmed"=>true}}
```

I need a mongodb query to search for the ttoken record by mobile number and then delete that record. The DB used is MongoDB. Any guidance or help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MongoDB 'dot notation' for the embedded element, which means the "key" must be a string type of notation. Also apply [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to match where the key in the has is present and the [`.unset()`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#unset) method from mongoid:

```
User.where('_id'=> userId, 'ttokens.919839398393'=> { '$exists' => true }).unset(
  'ttokens.919839398393'
)
```

This is effectively the [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator of MongoDB, which removes "keys" from the document by the path specified.

From the sample document this would match and remove the first key, leaving only the other.

Comment: Thank you for response Blakes. It works well, however, it would be great if you could please suggest how to delete this entry, only in a particular user's DB. Your current query deletes ttokens of 919839398393 across all the user's DB. I would like to delete it only in a particular user's DB. I have the mobile no. of that particular user and I can search him using his number.

Comment: @user1903022 your question only shows this field. How are we matching the user? The id value? Extra fields in the query are just a comma seperated list. See I've added one.

Comment: Thank you Blakes. You made my day. It works perfectly well now :-). Also, basically I am an Android developer, just started learning Ruby on Rails for backend, so, it would be very kind of you, if you could please suggest from which sources to gain more expertise in RoR. Thank you once again.