# Get the mobile number of the user in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I have to search for all the details of a user, I can use the following query:

```
User.find_by(token: '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc123450a0c5acb9f')
```

This MongoDB query returns all the details of the user, having the above token. Instead of getting all the details, how can I get only the mobile number of this user? Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
In the rails console, when I give the above query, following is the output that I get:

```
irb(main):013:0> user = User.find_by(token: '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a60a0c5acb9f')

=> #<User 
     _id: 55a197716c6f6b16f040000,
     email: nil, 
     encrypted_password: "", 
     reset_password_token: nil,
     reset_password_sent_at: nil, 
     remember_created_at: nil, 
     sign_in_count: 0,
     current_sign_in_at: nil,
     last_sign_in_at: nil,
     current_sign_in_ip: nil, 
     last_sign_in_ip: nil, 
     name: nil,
     mobile: "917572077896",
     imei: "911372398074425",
     uid: nil, 
     provider: nil, 
     coords: [{
        "lat"=>12.9715967, 
        "lng"=>77.5989627, 
        "tim"=>2015-07-11 19:19:39 UTC}
     ],
     token: "6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a20a0c5acb9f",
     xytoken: "3b62620961537994475f6c0a4d5b98fe3994f2",
     stoken: nil, 
     n_stoken: 0, 
     ttokens: {
        "918127885111"=> {
            "token"=>"255cb70926978b93e0e67edb52fa23a163587b4b",
            "confirmed"=>true
        }, 
        "919839398393"=> {
            "token"=>"f704e803061e594150b09ad8acabfc6105ac85ab",
            "confirmed"=>false
        }
    },
    tracking_enabled: true>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
#<mobile: "917572077896">
```

So, instead of getting all the details, of the user having token '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a60a0c5acb9f', I would like to get the value of his key 'mobile' only.

Comment: Can you provide details about what driver or potential ORM you are using?

Comment: Have you not basically asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446041/how-to-search-for-a-record-and-then-delete-it? The `.update()` statement shows matching your data structure. Or is this question asking how to match the "parent" key name given a "sub-key" name like this? For which all the data detail is missing from the question.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: That works well for a particular case of using 'ttokens.919839398393', but doesn't give the desired results when trying to generalize the query, like 'ttokens.(user.mobile)' and then using it the users_controller.rb file of your Ruby on Rails environment.

Comment: Can you add some data to "this" question so it shows excactly what the data looks like  in your collection and what you are expecting to achieve. I't very unclear right now.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Sure, please refer the edit.

Comment: So you seem to be asking what is in that link. Basically the whole model still gets loaded with 'nil' properties if you use `.only()`, but you can of course just extract the property you want.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Could you please give an example. I seem to get an error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `only' for #<User:0x007f49faefb0c8>

Comment: An example is right in the duplicate: `User.where(:token => '...').only(:mobile).first`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Unfortunately, I am still getting the error: 
NoMethodError: undefined method `only' for #<User:0x007f49f9d3fbe0>

Comment: That's because you're still using `find_by` or you're calling `only` after `first`.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's what I am doing:
irb(main):077:0> user = User.where(:token => '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a6450a0c5acb9f').only(:mobile).first

That's what I get:
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>

Comment: And what happens if you call `mobile` on it?

Comment: @muistooshort: Then:
irb(main):078:0> user = User.where(:atoken => '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a6020a0c5acb9f').only(mobile).first
NameError: undefined local variable or method `mobile' for main:Object

Comment: @BlakesSeven: It would be very nice of you, if you could please help.

Comment: @user1903022 They meant `User.where(:token => '6619aba61f14ed7b32c3be0cc5a6450a0c5acb9f').only(:mobile).first.mobile` which is the same as what is being done in the examples listed in the linked question.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Okay, thanks. It was helpful :-).